# gstreamer RTSP on ubuntu - WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "rtspsrc"

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer, rtsp

Getting my self in a bit of a state. I've been trying to get opencv to use gstreamer and after finally manage to compile from source and have it pick up gstreamer its not working.

So i've taken to the command line to make sure its working there first, and I've tried everything but gstreamer is not picking up "rtspsrc".

I'm running the below in the terminal.

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:[**mypassword**]@192.168.0.40/h264Preview_01_main ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink max-buffers=1 drop=true")
```

But am getting the below error, does anyone know why this might be?

```
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "rtspsrc"
```

Running ubuntu - gstreamer1.0

Comment: Make sure you can ping the camera.

Comment: yes camera works fine using ffmpeg in opencv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rtspsrc is part of the Gst-plugins-good. Are you sure you have those installed?

If not, try installing it using:

```
apt install libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
```

To check if GStreamer can find the plugin. Run the following in the terminal:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 rtspsrc
```

If it returns all kinds of details, it can correctly find the plugin. If it cannot find it, it will return:

```
No such element or plugin 'rtspsrc'
```

---

(edit)

As OP said, for him

```
which gst-launch-1.0
```

returns

```
/home/lewis/anaconda3/bin
```

So apparently GStreamer is installed through Anaconda, which means it is probably easiest to also install the plugins through Anaconda. I don't have any specific experience with Anaconda, but it think the following should work:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gst-plugins-good
```

If other elements are also missing, plugins-base/bad can also be installed

Comment: It returns - No such element or plugin 'rtspsrc'. I've tried removing and reinstalling with no luck

Comment: I edited my answer based on your response below.

Are you using gstreamer with Anaconda on purpose? Or is it your goal to use the 'normal' gstreamer?

You could also try running '/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0' instead of just 'gst-launch-1.0'. This should use the non-anaconda version of gstreamer

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that the Anaconda version of GStreamer was found and not the one installed in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when using apt-get the plugins are installing to /usr/bin

BUT

```
which gst-launch-1.0
```

returns /home/lewis/anaconda3/bin

I'm not sure what to do yet, but have opened a new question on the linux pages.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/575262/whereis-gstreamer-located-in-two-paths-causing-issues

Answer (score 0):

Note that although RTSP components are on the `good` set of plugins on Debian/Ubuntu they have been separated into their own package:

`sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-rtsp`

Comment: even after this i'm still getting (base) lewis@lewis-MS-7A34:~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7$ gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "rtspsrc".